# tracking down root cause for openldap account locking

Tags: ldap, openldap

This has happened to me in the past, and I've been able to find an email client or something random like that which was over zealously trying to login with the wrong password, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what service or agent is locking me up.  When you ldapsearch my record, you see the obvious:

```
    pwdChangedTime: 20150219184855Z
    pwdFailureTime: 20150219225804Z
    pwdFailureTime: 20150219225809Z
    pwdFailureTime: 20150219225812Z
    pwdFailureTime: 20150219225815Z
    pwdFailureTime: 20150219225818Z
    pwdFailureTime: 20150219225820Z
    pwdAccountLockedTime: 20150219225820Z
```

I can unlock my account, but something is hitting it roughly every 3 seconds.  I'd like to stop that thing. I was expecting to find the requestor's IP in the ldap logs, but nothing is in there that I can see off hand.

Is there an ldapsearch or some other tool to allow me to find out what ip is calling with my username?

Comment: If it's not LDAPs, you can do a packet capture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting `slapd` with `-d 8` should log the connections.  There are additional debug bits which will provide additional information.

However it may be simpler to use `netstat -ant` and filter out the connections to the LDAP (389) or LDAPS (636) with grep.  This should indicate where the connections are originating.  If you have root access on the originating system, you can use `netstat -antp` to determine the program originating the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback BillThor -- that did give me lots of insight into my ldap infrastructure (we have three load balanced ldap clusters all in sync with one another), but unfortunately the list was about 800 hosts long and constantly changing (even after I removed the other ldap servers).

Lucky for me, splunk had enough data for me to find the login error, which I then used the conn ID to link to the whole auth conversation to hunt down the IP.  It was a `watch` process running under screen from a month ago.  Ack!  Thanks again for the excellent input though.